# CodeIgniter Session won't destroy

Tags: codeigniter, session, logout

I have got my login function to work which then has an array to show the session data but when I click logout it redirects me to the login page but does not clear the session data if I manually load up the members page.

Controller Function

```html
public function logout(){

        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('site/login');
    }
```

```html
public function members(){
        
        if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
        $data['title'] = "Members";
        $this->load->view('view_header');
        $this->load->view("view_members", $data); 
        }
        else{
            redirect('site/restricted');
        }

    }
```

Model

```html
class Model_users extends CI_Model {
    
    
    public function canLogin(){
        
        $this->db->where('Username', $this->input->post('Username'));
        $this->db->where('Password', md5($this->input->post('Password')));
        
        $query = $this->db->get('user_registration');
        
        
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
        
    }
      
    
}
```

Members View

```html
 <?php
 
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r ($this->session->all_userdata());
 echo "</pre>";
 
 ?>
 
 <a href='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/site/logout"?>'>Logout</a>
```

Not sure what I'm missing here since the logout function runs but doesn't seem to clear the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create a function in your Home controller cleaning the cache like this:

```
function clear_cache()
{
    $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
}
```

So call it from your controller's constructor

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->clear_cache();
    }
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: 2017 and i found the same problem with old web ci app, this fixed my problem, thanks man !